# Unlocking features via promo code that are also offered in an out-of-app subscription

Tags: iphone, ios, subscription, outlook-redemption, promotions

I'm interested in unlocking features for a fixed time period in my iphone app via promo code. These same features are also offered for subscription outside of the app store. Is this still legitimate? It's imperative that the app isn't rejected by the app store for violating the terms of service.

Moreover, if we allowed the user to 'spend points' for this subscription (in app), would this be a violation? I suspect so but thought I would ask.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen apps out there that use earned points to unlock features, or the user could just speed up the process and purchase it with an in app purchase, so that seems fine

Having out of app subscriptions seem debatable but I feel like they would be fine - apple would still earn a profit as people would be encouraged to buy out of the app.

Keep in mind that apple will take out a cut for themselves on every purchase (including in app)

And welcome to StackOverflow :D

Comment: In this scheme, apple isn't taking a cut. We aren't offering in-app subscriptions or purchases through the app store. Apple's policy on out-of-app subscriptions are that you can offer them but not link to an external source (saying "Go to www.mysite.com" is okay though). Again, no cut for Apple. Thanks for the info though.